# AKS: MongoError: not master

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, bitnami, azure-aks

I'm using mongodb replicaset in Azure Kubernetes. I have two pods running for mongodb. I have created a service to connect both pods, which is working perfectly fine. But looks like now it is giving error while connecting to secondary pod:

[amqp] Channel consume error: MongoError: not master
errmsg: 'not master',
code: 10107,
codeName: 'NotMaster'

Can you please help me in case of I'm missing something

Source of MongoDB: [Bitnami MongoDB Helm](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/mongodb)

Comment: You need to provide more details. What aks version is that, your configuration, steps to reproduce, more logs, as one entry might not help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try to use `externalAccess.enabled=true` parameter so you don't have to create the services manually. In combination with that, you could also use `externalAccess.autoDiscovery.enabled=true`.

```
$ helm install mongodb bitnami/mongodb \
  --set architecture=replicaset \
  --set externalAccess.enabled=true \
  --set externalAccess.autoDiscovery.enabled=true \
  --set rbac.create=true
```

BTW, it could be good to see more details of your installation parameters and environment so that we could help better.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your reply.
We want to keep service internal only i.e. no internet access. I believe this parameter will enable internet access

Comment: It is not actually to the internet, it means external to the k8s cluster, in fact, you can use `externalAccess.service.type=NodePort` or even `externalAccess.service.annotations` in order to say your cloud provider that you want an internal load balancer.